# Thinking Sphinx on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thinking-sphinx

Installed Thinking Sphinx via Gemfile:

```
gem 'thinking-sphinx',:git => 'git://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx.git'
```

When I run `rake thinking_sphinx:configure`, I get:

```
Unsupported version: 2.0.5
```

... but it generates the config file fine. When I run rebuild (which also starts sphinx), everything looks okay. But when I fire up the Rails console (or my app, for that matter), I get this, and I'm confused why:

```
Unsupported version: 2.0.5


For more information, read the documentation:
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html

/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/assertions.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': Test is not a module (TypeError)
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/test/unit/testcase.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:299:in `initialize_console'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/jim/projects/rubymine/xx/script/rails:6:in `require'
from /Users/jim/projects/rubymine/xx/script/rails:6:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Try installing without the git path, just `gem 'thinking-sphinx'`. Maybe the version of the git has some bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails wizard I know fixed this project by using these:

```
gem 'riddle', '1.5.1' 
gem 'thinking-sphinx', '2.0.11', :require => "thinking_sphinx"
```